# Two "expression expected" errors in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, expression

I'm using Visual Basic 2008. I went to publish my project, and I got two "Expression expected" errors. I am very new to Visual Basic - I just started last night. The code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.zudostudios.com")
End Sub

Private Sub GoBtn1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(addressTxt.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addressTxt.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addressTxt.TextChanged
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.zudostudios.com")
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)      Handles Label1.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a copy paste mistake.

You have implemented the following code.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addressTxt.TextChanged
End Sub
```

But when calling to a method `TextBox1_TextChanged` the `Handles addressTxt.TextChanged` is useless.

Correct code should be:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1_TextChanged(sender, e)
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that new code. I still get 2 expression expected errors. Each one takes me to oe of the "ByVals" in your code.

Comment: Thanks - nevermind though, I figured out how to do a WebBrowser1.refresh() or whatever it was. It works now, thanks :)